# Pass Date Range to seperate inputs

Tags: javascript, html, daterangepicker

I am jsut learning JS and have a question about using a date range picker.  I want to use this type of selection but how would I go about passing start and end times to the startDate and endDate input boxes?

```
HIDDEN: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="startDate" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="Start Date">
HIDDEN: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="endDate" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="End Date">

SHOWN on PAGE: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" id="demo" >

$('#demo').daterangepicker({
    ranges: {
        'Today': [moment(), moment()],
        'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
        'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
        'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
        'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
        'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    },
    "startDate": "03/27/2020",
    "endDate": "04/02/2020"
}, 
    );
});
```

I searched on here but everything pointed to python scripts.  This is JS within an HTML page.

Thank you

Comment: Im not sure what you are want to reach.

Comment: currently the JS puts the date like 03/20/2020 - 03/31/2020 in one input.  I want it to split the dates and put them in the respective inputs.

Comment: im sorry. i cant follow you. Are you want to use one datepicker with on selector ?

Comment: Yes.  Im not sure how to make it clearer.

Comment: Id like the start date to show in the input field startdate and the end date to show in the enddate input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by assigning to inputs in JS using the correct method.

```
  $('input.date_range').daterangepicker({
    autoApply:true,
    ranges: {
       'Today': [moment(), moment()],
       'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
       'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
       'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
       'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
       'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
   },



   });

  $('form').submit(function (ev, picker) {
      [startDate, endDate] = $('.date_range').val().split(' - ');
      $(this).find('input[name="datemin"]').val(startDate);
      $(this).find('input[name="datemax"]').val(endDate);
  });
```

Form

```
  <form>

  <div class="form-row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-auto">
      <input type="hidden" name="datemin">
      <input type="hidden" name="datemax">
      <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInput">Select Date Range</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 date_range" id="inlineFormInput" size="30">
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/erkc64ot/5/

Answer (score 0):

Based on [daterangepicker](https://www.daterangepicker.com/)'s first example, it looks like you could do something like this:

```html
<input type="text" name="daterange" value="" />
<input type="text" name="startdate" value="" />
<input type="text" name="enddate" value="" />

<script>
$(function() {
  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    opens: 'left'
  }, function(start, end, label) {
    $input[name="startdate"].value = start.format('MM-DD-YYYY')
    $input[name="enddate"].value = end.format('MM-DD-YYYY')
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this but it appears to not work.  Sorry for the late reply to this.  https://jsfiddle.net/erkc64ot/